# Can't make query work with variable

Tags: php, sql, joomla

i have this query

```
AND i.state = 1
AND i.language = "'.$mylang.'"
AND i.access IN ('.implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels()).')
```

i should get the content only for the current language) the strange thing is that with the php variable $mylang it's not working ( writing it-IT ) i get the content.
I allready checked the result of $mylang and its = to it-IT .

any clues?
thanks.

Comment: post the complete query code.

Comment: Pl check all variable with values and then pass to query ....

Comment: From the MySQL documentation: `the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier.`

Comment: You don't have to use the `.` to concat strings when you are inside a string.

Comment: If you are in Joomla you should us the Joomla query building API.  right now even if you take the "" out as @Diamondo2 says you are looking for rows where the language field is set to  '.$lang,'  .... you just need $mylang  but you should be using quoting so if you have a Joomla database object, $db, you want $db->quote($mylang);

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you could copy whole query.

Comment: $myQuery = 'SELECT 
         i.* 
         FROM #__content as i 
         WHERE 1=1 
         AND i.state = 1
         AND i.language =        "'.$mylang.'"
     AND i.access IN ('.implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels()).')
     AND i.publish_up <= "'.$jdate->toSql().'"
     AND (i.publish_down = 0 OR i.publish_down >= "'.$jdate->toSql().'")';

Comment: @Adrian - please add it your your initial question rather than a comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the 1=1 subclause in your WHERE but ignoring that
Try something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->query(true);
$query->select('i.*')
    ->from($db->quteName('#__content')) 
    ->where($db->quoteName('i.state') . ' = 1')
    ->where($db->quoteName('i.language') .' = '  $db->quote($mylanguage))
    ->where($db->quoteName('i.access') . ' IN (' . impode(',',$user->getAuthorisedViewLevels()) . ')' )
 ...
;
$db->set($query);
....
```

Also, if your queries are not working the best thing is to do `echo $query->dump()` to see the rendered query, also you can just look at the queries if you turn the debugger on.